# Want to build attendance tracking system with GPS latitude and longitude

Tags: android, gps

build a algorithm to find a polygon build by four sets of lat long.. and passing current lat long to find whether a set of lat long belong to that polygon or not. But the the current latiitude and longitude is not accurate . in android using GPS and network  system to tracking current latitude and longitude.

```
 public void find current_lat_long(){
com.example.gps.AppLocationService appLocationService = new com.example.gps.AppLocationService(
            Map_Location.this);
    Location gpsLocation = appLocationService
            .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Location nwLocation = appLocationService
            .getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (gpsLocation != null) {
        latitude_gps_calc_lat = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude_gpa_calc_lng = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
        constant.lat=String.valueOf(gpsLocation.getLatitude());
        constant.longitude=String.valueOf(gpsLocation.getLongitude());
        constant.flag_gps=false;
        String latlong_gps = String.valueOf(gpsLocation.getLatitude())+String.valueOf( gpsLocation.getLongitude());
//       lat1_string=constant.lat;
//          long_1_string=constant.longitude;

           lat4_string=constant.lat;
            long_4_string=constant.longitude;

        return true;
    }
    else if (nwLocation != null)
        {
                latitude_network_provider = nwLocation.getLatitude();
                longitude_network_provider = nwLocation.getLongitude();
                constant.flag_network=false;
                latlong__network_provider =String.valueOf(latitude_network_provider)+String.valueOf(longitude_network_provider);

                constant.lat=String.valueOf(latitude_network_provider);
                constant.longitude=String.valueOf(longitude_network_provider);
                   lat4.setText(constant.lat+constant.longitude);
                   lat4_string=constant.lat;
                    long_4_string=constant.longitude;

            return true;


    }
```

}

Please help to find accurate lat long to tracking that lat long belong to the particular polygon.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Please clarify your needs

Comment: Do you want to find those lat long points? Or check whether a new point belongs to this polygon?

Comment: just getting blur picture of what you are trying to do, please **bullet point** your requirements,or coding doubt etc.

Comment: Firstly manually I add four lat longs from four sides of a place using gps tracking system.here are the lat longs :22.568621666667,88.434095
22.568546666667,88.433981666667
22.569045,88.434271666667
22.5706928,88.4320082  and the entered current lat long is 22.5705633 and 88.4315515 but they are not accurate so.. the output returned from the calculation is alwaz false.. i need to find out accuare lattitude and longitude , so that i can find whether a particular place is inside that lat longs or not.

Comment: @sucharitaganguly See my answer below. You can find current lat long using that code. Hope that helps you finding the location.

Comment: @sucharitaganguly To find whether a point is in polygon or not, which code are you using? Are you using containsLocations method from PolyUtil. Please do check you function to find that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find location using the below code:

**Declare the variable:**

```
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener ll;
```

**Start Location listener :**

```
    lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ll = new startLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,ll);
```

**Location listener:**

```
class gpsLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            String latitude =  location.getLatitude();
            String longitude = location.getLongitude();                
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}
```

**After finding location you can stop listener using this in onLocationChanged:**

```
 lm.removeUpdates(ll);
 lm = null;
```

Comment: It is working, you can get lat long using this. Where did you call this? Calling this listener would provide you accurate location, in onLocationChanged method of listener.

Comment: yeh i know its not working in the sense that when i move from one place to another it returns the same lat longs , when i want to set four lat long points ,i changed my location but location listener is not updating accordingly

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Please make bit more clear. This listener will work until the activity is there, you will get the new locations in onLocationChanged (provided you dont remove the listener). To do a background update, use it in a thread or service. If you want the location of only those four points, then start the listener when you are on that point and save the lat long and then stop listener, then proceed to next point and repeat the same

Comment: actually in practical scenario when i doing work with that set of code in a place , it not returning the proper lattitudes and longitudes.,i tested it several times at all.

Comment: Did you test in on phone by moving or in emulator by passing values to device? I tested it here, it is returning me fresh lat long as changes occur.