# Accurate latitude and longitude not returned?

Tags: android

I want to find current location of a user by android , but always returning a location within the 10 metre of a particular area. It does not return the actual place. I am using google play services location api to find the current location instead.

How did I retrieve accurate latitude and longitude?

Comment: what problem in lat lang

Comment: have you try using GPS ?

Comment: yes i already tried with gps but the returned data is not accurate

Comment: actually i need to build a application which will form a polygon with four sets of lat longs and then find a place that is within that surrounded polygon.i am collecting four lat longs by moving four diiferent place and when i am in between the place of polygon i found that the returned value is outside the polygon. we are tracking the lat longs are as follows 22.5682203,88.4346739
22.568792,88.4344252
22.5688278,88.4344034
22.5688277,88.4344033 and inside that formed polygon i found current lat long is 22.5705803 and 88.4316084 but returns its outside the polygon

Comment: I'm fairly certain it all depends on how many GPS satellites your device can see at any given time. Are you getting different results when you use Google Maps or others that provide location?

Comment: I think 10 meters is about as good as you can expect in a civilian GPS system without *ionospheric corrections*. See [Is Military GPS More Accurate Than Civilian GPS?](http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/#difference).

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions on SO. You have already posted a similar question and asked for help few days back. Modify it to get new solutions, rather than posting as new question to get new answers everyday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119183/want-to-bulid-attendance-tracking-system-with-gps-lattitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 1):

Try this . I hope it helps you lot

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    LocationManager lm;
    private static TextView lt;
    private static TextView ln;
    private static TextView ac;
    private static WebView webview;
    String provider;
    Location l;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ln = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lng);
        lt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
        ac = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acc);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // get location service
        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGPSProviderEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean isNETProviderEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if( !isGPSProviderEnabled || !isNETProviderEnabled) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Location is off");  // GPS not found
            builder.setMessage("Location setting open"); // Want to enable?
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);
            builder.create().show();
            return;
        }
        Criteria c = new Criteria();
        // criteria object will select best service based on
        // Accuracy, power consumption, response, bearing and monetary cost
        // set false to use best service otherwise it will select the default
        // Sim network
        // and give the location based on sim network
        // now it will first check satellite than Internet than Sim network
        // location
        provider = lm.getBestProvider(c, false);

        // now you have best provider
        // get location
        l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l != null) {
            // get latitude and longitude of the location
            double lng = l.getLongitude();
            double lat = l.getLatitude();
            double acc = l.getAccuracy();
            // display on text view
            updateview(lng, lat, acc);
        } else {
            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, this);
            ln.setText("No Provider");
            lt.setText("No Provider");
            ac.setText("No Provider");
        }
    }

    // If you want location on changing place also than use below method
    // otherwise remove all below methods and don't implement location listener
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
        double lng = l.getLongitude();
        double lat = l.getLatitude();
        double acc = l.getAccuracy();
        updateview(lng, lat, acc);

    }

    private void updateview(final double lng, final double lat, final double acc) {
        Log.v(TAG, "updateview");
        Log.v(TAG, "lng:"+lng);
        Log.v(TAG, "lat:"+lat);
        Log.v(TAG, "acc:"+acc);
        ln.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
        lt.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        ac.setText(String.valueOf(acc));
        String URL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+lat+","+lng+"&zoom=15&size=500x200&markers=color:red|"+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=false";
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.loadUrl(URL);
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                  switch (event.getAction()) {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                      String uri = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "geo:%f,%f", lat, lng);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(intent);  
                        return v.performClick();
                  }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onProviderDisabled"+arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onProviderEnabled"+arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onStatusChanged"+arg0);
    }
```

Here is XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#89b" >
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
   android:text="Longitude:" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/lng"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
   android:text=""
   android:textSize="30sp" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView3"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_below="@+id/lng"
   android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
   android:text="Latitude:" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/lat"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lng"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
   android:text=""
   android:textSize="30sp" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView4"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
   android:layout_below="@+id/lat"
   android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
   android:text="Accuracy:" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/acc"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lat"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
   android:text=""
   android:textSize="30sp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/acc"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```